# AEM 6.1 configuration for Search Sugesstion and StopWords

Tags: aem

We are using AEM6.1 and implementing OOTB search functionality. The requirement is that we have to implement StopWords(will not user to search common words such as like,for,is) and Spellcheck(Did you mean ?) features as part of this implementation.Can anyone suggest as the best way to achieve this requirement.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can configure stopwords in your oak index definition.

```
-fulltextIndex
      - jcr:primaryType = "oak:QueryIndexDefinition"
      - compatVersion = 2
      - type = "lucene"
      - async = "async"
      + analyzers
        + default
            - class = "org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer"
            - luceneMatchVersion = "LUCENE_47" (optional)
            + stopwords (nt:file)
```

Please check the following documentation on Oak[1].

To see more details on this it is better to follow the JIRA story on the Jackrabbit Oak Jira[2]. This was part of Oak1.1.2 and since AEM6.1 comes with Oak1.2.2, you should be able to configure the stop words directly.

[1] - https://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/query/lucene.html

[2] - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OAK-2177